# Migrating TFS 2005 to TFS 2010

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, tfs, tfs-migration

I have read the Microsoft documentation on a migration upgrade to a different server. Our current setup uses SharePoint 2.0 which we will no longer need, and is on SQL Server 2005.

The recommended steps mention backing up the existing databases and restoring them to SQL Server 2008. I'm guessing that the accounts would not be included in this?

My question is this: would it be possible to use the Database Publishing Wizard within VS 2010 to script the existing SQL Server 2005 DBs and target them for SQL Server 2008 (using the drop down list within the wizard)? I know that the wizard usually includes all security info but I'm not sure if this approach is supported for this type of migration and I can find no existing documentation which even mentions the use of the Database Publishing Wizard. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your setup, you may need to add the SQL Logins to the new server. But I do not think that the database publishing wizard would help you with that.

For a good description of how to do the upgrade see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wlennon/archive/2009/12/02/upgrade-tfs-2010-from-tfs-2005-or-tfs-2008.aspx

Comment: Marking as answer (really helpful link). But I'm still curious as to whether or not the Publisher Wizard would be a slicker way to do this...